EC2 User Data Script Not Executing NodeJs File On Launch or Reboot
I'm trying to build a user data file to be included on each and every AWS EC2 instance I launch.
The data should be executed on initial launch, as well as on every reboot/restart.
It is supposed to create/overwrite a .env file using params passed in the data itself, and then run a nodejs app that comes as part of the custom system image.
This is what I have so far
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#!/bin/bash

# Create .env file -- This works
cat << EOF > /home/ec2-user/.env
UN=XXX
PW=XXX
CID=XXX
KEY=XXX
EOF

# Start the Node.js app --Nothing happens here
screen -d -m node index.js

--//--

With a bit of additional logging, I have managed to get the machine to output the following: Node.js is not installed.
However, I don't believe this is correct, because when I SSH into the machine directly and run node --version it spits back v20.14.0.
Could this be a timing issue? Should I be calling another shell script included in the machine image directly instead to execute the file?
I have also tried to remove screen and just run node index.js directly, which no success.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

If this is a one-time script that does some setup work then exits, it's ok to be in a userdata script. If it's actually your persistent web application then this is not the place to run it.

@jarmod setting up the .env file should be a one-time thing, otherwise we have to be sure the app runs immediately each and every launch, reboot, etc. How would you suggest we do this if not in user data? I haven't seen a preferred alternative out there.

It sounds like you're saying that this is indeed a one-time setup for .env files etc. so doing it in userdata is absolutely fine.

@jarmod for the .env files yes, for automatically running the other screen command... maybe not so much. That screen command must be run right away on every boot/reboot

What are you using screen for? If you're simply trying to run some kind of persistent application or application server then use a tool designed for that e.g. pm2.

The issue was that, by default, user data scripts execute on the machine as root user. So when I would ssh in as the default ec2-user and look for any sign the script executed, it wouldn't be there (root made it, not ec2).
To get around this, I just modified the user data script to execute relevant commands as ec2-user rather than root.
sudo -u ec2-user -i <<'EOF'
commandhere
EOF

Handled it.
